# Nothing happens when I press play in Unity3D

Tags: unity, c#

Hello everyone I am making my first game, things were going well but suddenly nothing happens when I press play, I have already update to the newest unity version but it persists.

I have the main camera selected, layers seem fine, I rested the camera position and also tried to switch to 3d view. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

You can download the game project file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0c64y0ats33f79i/Energy%20Manager.rar?dl=0

Any help is very much appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scene is empty. You didn't save the scene, where you did all the work. When you get done with work, then save the scene (Ctrl + S). It will save a scene file through that Unity maintains the scene work.

Comment: Having a saved scene is not required to run things.  It just means you can reopen it later.

Comment: Never knows, may be hr closed it, or pressed Ctrl+N, as you see nothing in hierarchy except Main Camera

Comment: "You didn't save" is an accurate answer, its a possible *cause.*  The accurate answer is "Your scene is empty."

Comment: As you happy my friend :)

Comment: If he hits ctrl-S on his empty scene and saves it, does it start working? No.  It doesn't.  Ergo saving isn't the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that you have any scripts attached to the main camera (or any other game object).  Scripts need to be attached to a GameObject to run.*

*There are exceptions to this, as with any rule.  But in the situation you are in, what's important is that *no* scripts are attached, meaning their `Update()` method does not run.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by Opening "scene1" and adding it to the project. This way:

Double click "scene1" to open

File -> Build Settings -> Add Open Scenes

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just FYI: you can have multiple scenes and not need them in the build settings.  When you hit "play" the *current* scene will play.  The build settings tell Unity *which scenes you want in the exported executable.*  With the first (i.e. default) scene at the top.  Note: you cannot remove items from this list, but you can uncheck them so they aren't exported.